# Snapsvg copy path group from paper1 to paper2, fit inside responsive div

Tags: javascript, jquery, snap.svg

[JSFIDDLE here of my issue.](https://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/02eqtLg5/) The Brazil region should load inside the modal.

Learning `snap` and trying to get a region from a world map and copy it onto a bootstrap modal. So click on a region, an image of the region itself is used on the modal.

I have achieved this but the shape is off to the right of the new canvas. I understand this is to do with `viewbox` and transform coords of the svg group cloned. How do I "fit shape to viewbox?

Here's my code for copying the image, which of course is not working.

```
var m = Snap('#world-map');
var d = Snap('#svg-region');
var regionSVG = m.select('#Brazil');
var p = Snap.parse(regionSVG);
var g = d.append(p);
```

This copies the SVG content OK, but it is not visible on the modal. On inspect I can see it off to the right. How do I center the `Brazil` svg group (for example) in the svg on the bootstrap?

Comment: Are you placing that `<g>` inside the correct SVG XML code? Or just tossing it there, inside the modal?

Comment: Hi the SVG is getting placed correctly in the HTML. On inspect I see the "shape" is way off to the right of the svg view box. This is because it came from a large map file and it lives all the way to the right of 0, 0. I need to resize and reposition it relative to 0,0. Sort of top left of bbox = 0,0

Comment: It would be useful if you provide a minimal example on a jsfiddle. Basically I would probably look at doing a getBBox() on the element, and then taking the x,y,width,height of that, modify the svg viewBox to take that into consideration.

Comment: Hi @Ian, I added a JSFiddle. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you probably want to either clone() the Brazil g element, or possibly use a 'use' element to reference it.

In this case, I've simply cloned it, and added it to the modal svg...

```
var p = regionSVG.clone();
d.append(p);
```

Then we can get the bounding box, and create a viewBox from that...

```
var bb = regionSVG.getBBox();    
var vb = bb.x + ' ' + bb.y + ' ' + bb.width + ' ' + bb.height;
d.attr({ viewBox: vb})
```

And hey presto, it should now have the Brazil map.

You will probably want to do things like remove() on the element from the modal each time to clean up.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/02eqtLg5/17/)

Comment: Hi @Ian, you rock! Thanks for this.

Comment: Hey @Ian, thanks for this. I am very new to SVG to grappling concepts. Do you have a suggestion on how to keep the extracted regions on the same scale with each other? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean aspect ratio or scale (so a small country would look very small).

Comment: I want to retain aspect ratio, but make each region appear at scale to others. So the small ones will be small, the bigger ones fill the space more. I am trying to lock in a 200x200 px box centered in the modal, then fill this space with the svg and the region to scale centered in the svg view port. I have been at it for hours now! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Kinda like setting `zoom: 05` and then all images are rendered relative to each other at half their original size.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/0djhebes/ have a look at this fiddle for where I got to

Comment: Don't really understand the issue. Why do you need a zoom, if you need a fixed aspect ratio and scale, you have a fixed viewbox width/height, you just need to position x,y which you can get from the center of the viewbox. eg https://jsfiddle.net/0djhebes/14/

Comment: Sorry, I want the regions in the modal to be of a relative set size. So Brazil is big and fills the modal box, south Africa is smaller. Both displayed in the modal in relative sizes to each other. In the project I have other markers in the regions and right now some get zoomed and stretched because the smaller regions get enlarged.

Comment: I think there is a breakdown in explanation. Compare Brazil to New Zealand in https://jsfiddle.net/0djhebes/14/ NZ is smaller and aspect ratio is preserved. Maybe it's best to open a new question with a pic of what it shows vs what you want.

Comment: Hey @Ian, the changes you made to viewBox in the last fiddle seem to fix it. Thanks!